# undefined method in Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl and am running into a roadblock that doesnt seem to make sense.

I added a new method to the User class:

```
def full_name
  "test"
end
```

So when I do something like:

`test = User.new(name: 'Phil Collins', email: 't@gen.com')
test.full_name`

I get the error NoMethodError: undefined method `full_name'

Huh?  It's totally in the User class.  What am I missing?

Comment: No way to tell without any context. Are you in Rails console? Did you reload or restart?

Comment: Yes I am in rails console.  Let me restart the console and see.  The weird thing though is that I can still run other methods in that class...

Comment: So... adding a new method on the fly is against the rules in rails console?  You have to require it again it looks like.  Makes sense.  I don't have a lot of experience doing things in the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever Rails loads an application it will load all the classes in memory.

The Rails console invokes `Rails.application.initialize!` and will load the current code for the application.

Rails comes with nice features for developers to use while in development mode, notably spring.

https://github.com/rails/spring

However, this only works for development servers not the console.

There is a distinction, because when Rails loads a server then `Rails::Server` is defined. The console defines `Rails::Console`.

There is a way of reflecting code changes in console by using the `reload!`.

This will reflect code changes in the console, but there is a catch.

Old objects will not have changed, for this you must use `test.reload`.